# Does `__attribute((packed))` affect the alignment of other data structures?

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, padding, memory-alignment

I am trying to understand why alignment matters when dealing with data structures and why would it affect memory access performance. I stumbled upon a C syntax, `__attribute__((packed));` which what I understand, signals the compiler to not pad extra bits for alignment.

Say:

```
struct sampleStruct{
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t anotherFoo;
};
```

`foo` and `anotherFoo` equals to 16-bits but add an extra 16-bits to align with the natural word size of 32-bits processors.

Okay let's add another data structure:

```
struct anotherStruct{
    uint8_t fooZero;
    uint8_t fooOne;
}__attribute__((packed));

struct sampleStruct{
    uint8_t foo;
    uint8_t anotherFoo;
};
```

My question is, when initializing a packed data structure does it affect how other data structures are aligned in memory?

- Maybe the compiler re-orders how these data structure are created? (sampleStruct then anotherStruct)
- How about when there are two programs running on a system with the first program having an unaligned `struct` while the second program has an aligned `struct`? Would it leave a "gap" in memory or would the other `struct` be unaligned?

Sorry for the dumb question. This has been boggling my mind for quite some time. I want to know how memory alignment works and how it affects the processor in accessing memory.

Comment: "_but add an extra 16-bits to align with the natural word size of 32-bits processors._": Why do you expect that the structure will be aligned to the natural word size? I am not aware of an ABI which does it like that.

Comment: Why do you expect the order of structure declarations or even declarations _in other programs_ to have any relevance? I don't see how you make that connection. These are just declarations for C data types. They do not, as types, exist in memory at runtime.

Comment: Note that `__attribute__((packed))` is *not* "a C syntax".  It is a GNU C extension.  Strictly conforming C code cannot use it.

Comment: Here you have only defined _types_ not _instances_.  You question would make more sense if you declared adjacent instances of this types - adjacent type declarations make no difference - there is nothing to align or pack.  That said I would be horrified if the attributes of one type affected the alignment of an adjacent instance of another type.   Two separate processes will have separate memory spaces (virtualised on a modern OS), the data structure in one will not be anywhere near adjacent to the data structure of another - that is a Comp Sci question not programming - off-topic.

Comment: Alignment, ordering and packing are implementation defined.  The attribute guarantees that instances of that structure will be packed.  Although I'd expect that in any case - add a `uint32_t` after the two `uint8_t` I'd expect to see an effect - your test structures are not well designed to demonstrate packing.  Alignment may or may not be on a specific boundary, it is implementation dependent but not dependent on the specific packing of an adjacent type other than that it may take a different address relative to the other, but it will still have the same implementation defined alignment rules

Comment: Other than that, you really should not care - let the compiler do its thing.  If you really need to be sure how things are arranged in memory, code in assembly.  If you want to see how your compiler did it, use a debugger to watch the address of instances.  These things may be dependent no only on the compiler, but compiler options such as optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a variable that takes up *n* bytes can be read / written more effectively from memory if it resides at an address divisible by *n*.  On some processors (notably, not x86) attempting to read / write in an unaligned manner can cause a hardware trap.

So while packing a structure can reduce its size, it typically means slower memory access (if access can happen at all).

Packing a structure doesn't affect other structures or other types in general.  Each different type, whether it be a "base" type or a derived type, has its own alignment, so a variable of a given type is placed based on that type's alignment and where there may be available space.  The alignment of variables of some other type won't have a direct effect on that.

As for other processes, they are completely independent of each other so there's no reason that the internal data structures of one would have any affect on the internal data structures of another.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a variable that is `uint32_t` will placed at offset 4 while a variable that is a `char` will be placed at offset 5 and then if there's a variable with type `uint16_t` will be placed at offset 8? So variables, its type dictates where this variable is placed on memory? So I can imagine memory as being sparse?

Comment: @ronalddd Re "*a variable that is uint32_t will placed at offset 4*", No. It will (probably) be placed at an address or the next offset that's divisible by 4 (but that's entirely up to the compiler). /// Re "*while a variable that is a char will be placed at offset 5*", No, it will be placed at an address or the next offset that's divisible by 1. /// Re "*and then if there's a variable with type uint16_t will be placed at offset 8?*",  It will (probably) be placed at an address or the next offset that's divisible by 2.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand what alignment is or what packed does.

Alignment just means the object must be found/placed at an address that's divisible by some number. The alignment of one type has no bearing on the alignments of other types in this or other programs or processes, except when one type (array, union, structure) contains an object or another type.

Improper alignment can result in performance penalty (or worse).

Since your structure isn't affected by `packed` since it doesn't use any padding, so let's consider a different structure.

```c
struct yetAnotherStruct {
    uint8_t  foo1;
    uint32_t foo2;
    uint8_t  foo3;
};
```

Without `__attribute__((packed))`, this might compile as:

- The struct has a size of 12.
- `foo1` is a `uint8_t` found at offset 0.
- `foo2` is a `uint32_t` found at offset 4.
- `foo3` is a `uint8_t` found at offset 8.
- Must be placed at an address divisible by 4.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | padding   | 2             | 3 | padding   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

With `__attribute__((packed))`, this compiles as:

- The struct has a size of 6.
- `foo1` is a `uint8_t` found at offset 0.
- `foo2` is a `uint32_t` found at offset 1.
- `foo3` is a `uint8_t` found at offset 5.
- Must be placed at an address divisible by 1.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2             | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Those numbers are all it changes. Code that uses structs of this type uses those numbers to generate the appropriate CPU instructions to access, modify or allocate the structure. But that's it.

It doesn't affect any other structures in this or other programs in this or other processes (unless those structures contains this structure).